# How can I measure the overall memory requirements of a Python program

Tags: python

I have a financial pricing application written in Python 2.4.4 which runs as an Excel plugin. Excel has a 1GB memory limit for all addins, so if any addin process tries to allocate more than 1Gb in total it will cause Excel to crash.

I've recently made a change to the program which may have changed the overall memory requirements of the program. I'd like to work out if anything has changed sigifnicantly, and if not I can reassure my management that there's no chance of a failure due to an increase in memory usage.

Incidentally, it's possible to run the same function which runs in Excel from a command-line:

Effectively I can provide all the arguments that would be generated from Excel from the regular windows prompt. This means that if I have a method to discover the memory requirements of the process on it's own I can safely infer that it will use a similar amount when run from Excel.

I'm not interested in the detail that a memory profiler might give: I do not need to know how much memory each function tries to allocate. What I do need to know is the smallest amount of memory that the program will require in order to run and I need to guarantee that if the program is run within a limit of 1Gb it will run OK.

Any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Platform is Windows XP 32bit, python 2.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe XP keeps track of the peak memory requirements of a process (the way Linux does in /proc/pid/status for example). You can use third-party utilities such as [this one](http://www.loriotpro.com/ServiceAndSupport/How_to/How_to_control_Memory_usage.php) and set it to "poll" the process very frequently to get a good chance of grabbing the correct peak.

A better approach, though it doesn't answer your title question, is to try running the process under a [job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161(VS.85).aspx) with a [SetInformationJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216(VS.85).aspx) with a [`JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684156(VS.85).aspx) structure having a suitable `ProcessMemoryLimit` (e.g 1GB max virtual memory) and the right flag in `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION` to activate that limit. This way, if the process runs correctly, you will KNOW it has never used more than 1 GB of virtual memory -- otherwise, it will crash with an out-of-memory error.

This programmatic approach also allows measurement of peak values, but it's complicated enough, compared with using already packaged tools, that I don't think it can be recommended for that purpose. I do not know of packaged tools that allow you to use job objects to specifically limit the resources available to processes (though I wouldn't be surprised to hear that some are available, be that freely or commercially, I've never come upon one myself).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution might just be to run your app from the command line and use Task Manager to see how much memory it's using.

Edit:
For something more complicated have a look at this question / answer [How to get memory usage under Windows in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c)

Edit: Another option.  Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It's basically Task Manager on steroids.  It'll record peak usage of a process for you. (it's free so you don't have to worry about cost)

Comment: That can only tell me the instantaneous memory usage of an application. For example if it grabbed a load of memory and then released it I'd never know. So unfortunately this does not answer the question.