# How to get the space complexity of the C program?

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to make a `Online C Compiler` So multiple user can compile their code on a central server. And I can judge their code .

I want to calculate the time complexity ~ CPU Usages and the space complexity ~ Memory Usages of the C program. I am using `Windows XP` and `cygwin gcc 4.5 compiler`.

As a blog  I am trying to take the memory usages of a process by [pview](http://www.teamcti.com/pview/prcview.htm)

```
c:\cygwin\bin\gcc-3.exe -Wall source.c  -o a.exe 2>&1 | pv -o"%i\t%e\t%c2%%\t%m(K)\t%n" gcc-3.exe
```

It is return the memory usages by **gcc-3 is 3520 KB** in each cases either try to use **1000KB size or use no size i.e. simple printf statement**.

Can you help me by the automate way to calculate the memory usage or space complexity of the program this is not necessary to use the above code It is only I am trying.

Suggestion and Answers are welcomed

Comment: Are you interested in the program's memory consumption, or the compiler's? If you want to test the program, you should start by running it.

Comment: @ugoren If I calculate the program's memory consumption then it is good for me but it is too hard so I am trying to calculate the compiler's memory consumption and later on I will correlate the program's space usages to the compiler usages.  
Can some one help help me to get the solution?

Comment: There is not necessarily any correlation between the compiler's memory use and the final program's.

Comment: As @larsmans says, there will likely be no correlation. A program can that does `malloc(100000000)` or defines `int x[100000000]` won't cause the compiler to consume more memory than `malloc(1)` or `int x[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Cygwin, I guess you can use [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage). It contains many information about memory usage. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c) gives more info about how it works and a practical example.

For windows only program, you have [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c) for more info about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this thread (actually, a comment):

- [Set Windows process (or user) memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193596/1190965)

Practically this is all what you have --- Using ulimit (on Unix) or Job Object (on Windows) to cap the memory consumption of your compiler.  Predicting the memory consumption of your compiler beforehand for a given input source is, as @Yavar wrote, beyond our technology.

Btw why did you choose Cygwin on Win XP?  That combination is so notorious for being difficult to handle.  People usually use it in a last resort to port a software with Unix origin to Windows.  I hope you won't make a exploitable security hole in your "online compiler" system...