# get the process Memory Info in C

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, cygwin

I want to get the process memory Info in C. I am using Cygwin with GCC 4.5 on Windows XP. I include `#include <psapi.h>` and use `-lpsapi` when I build the program. 
I get the error

```
undefined reference to _getprocessmemoryinfo@12
```

Please tell the correct way to get the Process Info of Memory in C. I read the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282194/1249810), but it is not helping with my problem.

I use the code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    // Print the process identifier.

    printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );
    getchar();

    // Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                             PROCESS_VM_READ,
                             FALSE, 
                             processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        printf( "\tPageFaultCount: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PageFaultCount );
        printf( "\tYour app's PEAK MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tYour app's CURRENT MEMORY CONSUMPTION: 0x%08X\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PagefileUsage ); 
        printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

int main( )
{
  PrintMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcessId() );

    return 0;
}
```

Answers and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: One time i had this problem caused because I used -l sooner than the name of the .c file with main function.

Comment: @stupid_idiot is probably right. Please show the command line you use to build the program.

Comment: [This](http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009_05_14_archive.html) and [this](http://old.nabble.com/Build-problems-on-MinGW-td21445405.html) suggest that the order of `-lpsapi` in the command line is important. Try placing it at the end.

Comment: @Alex thnkx dear I got my answer.

Comment: @Alex: Maybe you should post your comment as an answer, so Code Breaker can accept it and it won't show up on the list of unanswered questions...

Comment: Any specific reason tu use NULL before? if (NULL == hProcess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009_05_14_archive.html) and [this](http://old.nabble.com/Build-problems-on-MinGW-td21445405.html) suggest that the order of `-lpsapi` in the command line is important. Try placing it at the end.