# C++ Program size in Memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to make a c++ program print out its own memory footprint.

Whats a good way to print out the KB of memory a c++ program is using at the current time?

I would need it for Linux and windows...so something platform independent....

Thank you,
MS

Comment: I know in Java there are tools like JProfiler thru which you can do this sort of thing. I'm be shocked if there wasn't an equivalent in c++

Comment: @user1291492 There are likely memory profilers, but I think OP asks for something programmatic.

Comment: You'll have to make it platform independent yourself via defines or whatnot.  C++ doesn't provide this capability, so any method will be platform dependent.  BTW, I found two answers to Windows and Linux on SO in one search

Comment: @MikeKwan: You can use a custom allocator to track all heap usage, but I don't think tracking stack/global usage is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is a mutli-platform way of doing this.
But you could use macros to do it like:

```
#ifdef __GCC__
//linux code
#else 
//windows code
#endif
```

heres a link for the windows method:

[How to get memory usage under Windows in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c)

and one for a linux method:

[How to get memory usage at run time in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Check out how it's implemented in LLVM:

[For Unix](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc?revision=154805)

[For Windows](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Support/Windows/Process.inc?revision=154805)

The relevant function is `GetTotalMemoryUsage()`.