# How to get system cpu/ram usage in c++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cpu, ram

I know this question has been asked multiple times. I've looked around a lot, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I did find this code [How to get memory usage under Windows in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c#comment16868612_8500024). But it will not compile, and all the other answers I've seen have been about how to get a single processes cpu/ram usage.

Comment: Dear popgalop. welcome to stackoverflow! that question have an accepted answer. If it's not what you are looking for,so edit this qustion to ask your own question and share some code so other user can help you with your own programing problem

Comment: what im confused what i was saying is when i tried that code it didnt work

Comment: @kfsone This question isn't a duplicate as the op clearly said that the code supplied within does not work for them.