# C++ Win32 realtime painting performance - how to know when the application can paint without using all CPU time

Tags: c++

In a display application we do use a large Window painting area. The display application gets so many updates for painting realtime data that all CPU time of the PC is used for painting. We do use InvalidateRect() and then paint the items in WM_PAINT message.

So we decided to use a dirty flag for each item to paint for reducing painting it.

How to know when the application can paint the items so that not all CPU time is consumed. Is there anything telling us that we can do our paint stuff now ?

Comment: You must be doing a tremendous amount of painting to us all of one core, let alone the whole CPU.  Are you using GDI, GDI+, DirectDraw, Direct2D, or something else?  Have you considered improving the drawing code so that it has less dependency on the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is updating so fast that painting each update is too much, you can use a timer.  Every (say) quarter second, the timer fires, and if any items are dirty, the timer handler calls `InvalidateRect()`.  Updating the data no longer invalidates; only the timer handler does that.

Edit: You could query Windows for the CPU load and if it's low, do the Invalidate immediately; see [How to get system cpu/ram usage in c++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218567/how-to-get-system-cpu-ram-usage-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: This was also our first idea. The disadvantage of this is that it always uses half of the quarter second per average till the update is done. If there is no (much) CPU load the update should be done immediate. If there is too many load the update shopuld be done a bit later.

Comment: You could query Windows for the CPU load and if it's low, do the Invalidate immediately; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've used is to make sure that **only one paint event** is on the event queue at a time.  You can use a boolean flag to mark when you begin updating and then reset the flag at the end of the WM_PAINT message (the end of the update process).  Of course, if you try to update the window again and the flag is already set, then don't do anything.  This will keep extra events from being piled into the queue, which can bog down your system.  It looks like you may have thought of this, but do this with the **entire** update in addition to the individual items.  Keep in mind that I'm only thinking of the updating of the windows themselves and not any underlying data.

One other thing I had to do was to "pump" (or process) the message queue during my (application) updates because updating a window (in my case) took several messages, ending with the WM_PAINT.

Another thing to watch out for is to **not use idle messages** for updating your interface.  This is a quick and dirty way of having the update happen automatically, but ends up being a really bad idea because the idling only happens when there are no other events on the message queue.  Of course, any time you move the mouse or press keys those events are placed onto the event queue and causes a "stall" of the update process.  The idle events can end up coming so fast that it causes your application to use most of the CPU processing power just for displaying data that hasn't even changed.  It's better to have your GUI only update when the underlying data it displays actually updates.

I had data coming in at 60Hz and updating lots of lists with columns of data as well as 3D stuff going on.  I finally had to prioritize the updates and just not update the lists for each cycle, but DO update the 3D data each cycle.  Updaing the lists at about 1-5 Hz was good enough for me and when combined with the techniques above resulted in a much improved and responsive system.