How to get the allocated memory of a process?
I want to get the allocated memory of a process.
Because I want to kill it if it uses too much memory.
I have got the process name and the PID.
I just need the amount of memory allocated and a function to kill the process.
This is code I have:
//-------------------------------------------------
// COMPILE WITH VS: cl /EHsc PrintProcess.cpp Advapi32.lib
//-------------------------------------------------

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                   PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                   FALSE, processID );

    
    if (NULL == hProcess ) return;
    
    HMODULE hMod;
    DWORD cbNeeded;

    if( !EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded) ) return;
    

    // Get the process name.
    GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );    

    // Print the process name and identifier.
    _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );

    // Release the handle to the process.
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void KillProcess(int MemorySize, DWORD processID)
{
    if(MemorySize<1024)
    {
            //How to kill the process here??
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( void )
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) ) return 1;
    


    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )
        {
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] ); 

            //How to get the allocated Memory here??
            KillProcess(MemorySize, aProcesses[i]); 
        }
    }
    
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------



When I have what I need I'm going to make a daemon with this.
I'm going to put it inside a thread and an infinite loop to verify the process continuously.
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// EDITED:
//------------------------------------------------------------

I'm sorry, I made a mistake.
It is actually a service.
But the problem is the same.
I have the name and PID of the service.
I need memory usage and a function to kill it.
just change this function "PrintProcessNameAndID()" for this other one.
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------
void MyEnumerateServices( DWORD processId )
{
    SC_HANDLE hSCM = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, 
        SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);


    if (hSCM == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    DWORD requiredBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD totalServicesCount = 0;
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        nullptr, 
        bufferSize,
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );

    std::vector<BYTE> buffer( requiredBufferSize );
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        buffer.data(), 
        buffer.size(),
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS services = 
        reinterpret_cast<LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS>( buffer.data() );
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < totalServicesCount; ++i )
    {
        ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS service = services[i];
        if ( service.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId == processId )
        {
            // This is your service.
            std::cout << service.lpServiceName << " ----> " << service.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId <<" <----- " <<std::endl;               
            
        }
    }

    CloseServiceHandle( hSCM );

}
//------------------------------------------------------------
//
//------------------------------------------------------------


I am more curious as the why you would kill a process like that. Is it a program you (or your company) developed yourself? If so fix the memory leaks ;) Adding unneeded "complexity" to your system (instead of fixing the real problem) will only make things worse over time.

Does this answer your question? Get memory usage of this process C++ Win32

You can query memory usage of another process via the system performance counters. The API is more friendly in C# (see here), but also available in C++. See here.

Hi Pepijn Kramer... no, it is not my program. I have not acess to the code. I can not modify it. I want use it... but i want kill it too (sometimes). :-)

Hi  Retired Ninja and  wohlstad: Thank you so much for the links. I going to read it right now.

The post in @RetiredNinja's comment might be more useful than it seems at first glance. Unlike the post title (mentioning "this process"), the API is not limited to the current process (although I haven't tried it).

i'm trying it... but seem the function don't like the references... this solution does not give errors but the function return zero/false.. So it does not work .-( ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32789877/9659027

Ok... it does work!! In those examples are using PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS as a typename and it does not... the typename is _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS (with underscore)... Thank you so much Red Ninja!!! :-)  .... Now i just need kill  the process!!

To kill a process given by the process HANDLE, you can use TerminateProcess.

I can't believe this... the process is a service... the function "GetProcessMemoryInfo()" does not work for services :-( Let's look for an equivalent function... I hope "TerminateProcess" works with services... Thank you so much
wohlstad!!
