# _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS is giving negative values about memory usage

Tags: c++

I am trying to get memory usage by my application. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c)

Here is code that I write but after 1 GB it is giving negative values.

```
    _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS info;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo( GetCurrentProcess( ), &info, sizeof(info) );
    int membyte = ((size_t)info.WorkingSetSize);
    QString s1 = "MB";

    double mem = membyte/1048576.0;
    if(mem>900.0)
    {
        mem = mem/1024.0;
        s1 = "GB";
    }

    double f,i,t1,t2;
    f = modf (mem , &i);
    f = f*100;
    t1 = modf(f,&t2);
    mem = i + (t2/100.0);
```

Comment: Isn't size_t unsigned? And your membytes is a (signed) int...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int membyte = ((size_t)info.WorkingSetSize);
```

Don't do that. There's no guarantee the working set size will be in the range an `int` can represent. Perhaps you want to use an `unsigned long` or, better yet, a `SIZE_T`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int membyte = ((size_t)info.WorkingSetSize);
```

to

```
SIZE_T membyte = info.WorkingSetSize;
```

The documentation says that the type of the WorkingSetSize member if SIZE_T.
You casted it info the int type which is signed, whereas SIZE_T is unsigned.