# Get memory and CPU usage using PID?

Tags: c++, winapi

Under windows, given a PID:

1) How to get the exact memory in bytes and
2) The exact CPU usage

consumed by that application right now?

Comment: [How to get memory usage under Windows in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question I linked to because that question doesn't address CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and specifically the WorkingSetSize field of the out parameter.
2. [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will let you know how much time your process has spent altogether in user & kernel space. It's up to you to calculate percentages, or whatever you want out of it.