# c++ get application memory peak (windows)

Tags: c++, memory

How I can get max memory peak when I running my application in windows?

Is there anything better then just looking at memory consumption of application in task manager?

I'm using VS2008, Win7 x64.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/how-to-get-memory-usage-under-windows-in-c

Comment: @TonyJiang I think I need some memory monitoring app, with method you provided I can get only current memory usage, not global max peak.

Comment: What about using GetProcessMemoryInfo() to get PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS.PeakWorkingSetSize?